# How to call an associated function of a struct with a generic type?

Tags: rust

I tried to create a `Link` trait and a struct `SinglLink` with a generic type which implements `Link`, but when I call the associated function of the struct, I get an error. Should I use a macro like `vec!`?

```
mod Link {
    use std::cell::RefCell;
    use std::collections::VecDeque;
    use std::fmt::Debug;
    use std::rc::Rc;

    trait Link {
        type Node;
        type Value;
        fn new(data: &mut VecDeque<Self::Value>) -> Self;
    }

    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct Node<T> {
        pub value: T,
        pub next: RefCell<Option<Rc<Node<T>>>>,
    }

    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct SinglLink<T> {
        pub header: RefCell<Option<Rc<Node<T>>>>,
        pub len: i32,
    }

    impl<T: Copy> Link for SinglLink<T> {
        type Node = Node<T>;
        type Value = T;
        fn new(data: &mut VecDeque<Self::Value>) -> Self {
            SinglLink {
                header: RefCell::new(None),
                len: 0,
            }
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::Link::SinglLink;
    use super::*;
    use std::cell::RefCell;
    use std::collections::VecDeque;

    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        let mut data: VecDeque<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].into_iter().collect();
        let single: SinglLink<i32> = SinglLink::new(&mut data);
    }
}
```

The error message:

```
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `new` found for type `Link::SinglLink<_>` in the current scope
  --> src/lib.rs:47:49
   |
20 |     pub struct SinglLink<T> {
   |     ----------------------- function or associated item `new` not found for this
...
47 |         let single: SinglLink<i32> = SinglLink::new(&mut data);
   |                                                 ^^^ function or associated item not found in `Link::SinglLink<_>`
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `new`, perhaps you need to implement it:
           candidate #1: `Link::Link`
```

Comment: Please don't ignore warnings from the compiler. Address them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two small mistakes are compounding here to make the error message not very helpful.

1. You've forgotten the `pub` on `trait Link`, so it is entirely inaccessible outside of the `Link` module. e.g. `pub trait Link { /* ... */ }`
2. You need to `use` the `Link` trait in the `tests` module for its methods to be available there. (Once you add the `pub`, the compiler error will tell you this nicely). e.g. `use super::Link::Link;`

Here's a working version of your code:

```
mod Link {
    use std::cell::RefCell;
    use std::collections::VecDeque;
    use std::fmt::Debug;
    use std::rc::Rc;
    pub trait Link {
        type Node;
        type Value;
        fn new(data: &mut VecDeque<Self::Value>) -> Self;
    }

    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct Node<T> {
        pub value: T,
        pub next: RefCell<Option<Rc<Node<T>>>>,
    }

    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct SinglLink<T> {
        pub header: RefCell<Option<Rc<Node<T>>>>,
        pub len: i32,
    }

    impl<T: Copy> Link for SinglLink<T> {
        type Node = Node<T>;
        type Value = T;
        fn new(data: &mut VecDeque<Self::Value>) -> Self {
            SinglLink {
                header: RefCell::new(None),
                len: 0,
            }
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::Link::SinglLink;
    use super::Link::Link;
    use super::*;
    use std::cell::RefCell;
    use std::collections::VecDeque;

    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        let mut data: VecDeque<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].into_iter().collect();
        let single: SinglLink<i32> = SinglLink::new(&mut data);
    }
}
```

([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=591415e1dbd788668839f73262f02124))

Comment: And you shouldn't call the module `Link` in the first place...